# Powershell filter for only unique entries in array from pipeline within custom module

Tags: powershell

This is a tangent/continuation from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636185/powershell-piping-multiple-pscustomobjects-drops-all-but-first-object) where I need to sanitize the input to one of my custom modules. Here's the code:

```
function Get-MyTest {

    param(
        [string[]]$MyInput
    )


    [array]$Output = @()
    $i=0

    foreach($Item in $MyInput){

        $i++

        $Output += [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $Item
            Id = $i
        }

    }

    return $Output

}

function Get-IncorrectResults {

    param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)][array]$MyIncorrectInput
    )

    process {
    
        foreach ($Item in $MyIncorrectInput) {
        
            Write-Host "Current object: $Item `n "

        }

    }

}
```

**Problem**
Adding `begin{}`, `process{}`, and `end{}` allows me to individually process each entry in the pipeline, but I can no longer filter the input. A user could end up with several identical objects in the `$MyIncorrectInput`, for example by doing:

```
[array]$TestVariable = @()
$TestVariable += Get-MyTest "Test1","Test2"
$TestVariable += Get-MyTest "Test3","Test2"
```

This would end up with two identical entries for Test2. If I then run either of the following:

```
Get-IncorrectResults -MyIncorrectInput $TestVariable
$TestVariable | Get-IncorrectResults
```

Then the Test2 object will be processed twice. Since the goal here is to use this in GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests for a RESTAPI then I can't have the code process the same entry (or ID) twice for DELETE since the resource has already been deleted. I therefore need to filter out to only process unique values.

**Attempted solution**
I tried to change the foreach loop to use `$item` in `$UniqueInput` instead, and add the following code:

```
$UniqueInput = $MyIncorrectInput | Get-Unique -AsString
```

If I add it in the `process{}` block it doesn't do anything, it still processes every entry including duplicates. If I add it in the `begin{}` block well then the value doesn't seem to carry over to the `process{}` block and the Write-Host section is empty because $UniqueInput seems to be empty.

Even changing to the following has no effect:

```
$UniqueInput = $MyIncorrectInput | Select-Object * -Unique
```

What is the correct way to filter an array input for only unique values in a custom module that needs to take the array from the pipeline? I don't need to have the full `PSCustomObject` be unique, it would be enough to have the `.Id` unique if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for `$TestVariable | Sort-Object { $_.Id } -Unique | Get-IncorrectResults` but not totally sure

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's right, I was going about it the wrong way, of course! Filter values in process, then run the foreach in the end block. Amazingly quick response, thank you so much! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: So what worked was put [array]$UniqueInput = @() in the begin block, put $UniqueInput += $MyIncorrectInput in the process block, and then put $UniqueInput = $UniqueInput | Sort-Object Id -Unique in the beginning of the end block and then run my RESTAPI calls. Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0), this class is designed to contain only unique elements:

```bash
function Get-IncorrectResults {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [array] $MyIncorrectInput,

        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $On,

        [parameter()]
        [switch] $CaseSensitive
    )

    begin {
        if($CaseSensitive.IsPresent) {
            return $hash = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new()
        }
        $hash = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    }
    process {
        foreach ($Item in $MyIncorrectInput) {
            if($hash.Add($Item.$On)) {
                $Item
            }
        }
    }
}

$TestVariable = @(
    Get-MyTest "Test1", "Test2"
    Get-MyTest "Test3", "Test2"
)

Get-IncorrectResults $TestVariable -On Id
$TestVariable | Get-IncorrectResults -On Id
```